# glTexImage3D throws exception

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am trying to compile this application in VS13. I linked all the libraries in this way:
glew32.lib from glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32
put glew32.dll in the same folder as Debug
linked glfw3

When I run this code it throws an exception at glTexImage3D; it says "Access violation executing location 0x00000000."

```
    #include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

GLenum volumeTexture;

int main() {
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW! I'm out!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));

    }

    // Use red to clear the screen
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    glGenTextures(1, &volumeTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, volumeTexture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

I noticed that the error resolves if I add

```
glTexImage3D = (PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexImage3D");
```

but then I get the same exception later when running glGenFramebuffers (I get it even if I comment the glTexImage3D line)
Am I linking something in the wrong way?

Comment: GL is a C API, it does not throw exceptions. Your OS might be raising an exception if, for instance, you try to call a function represented as a `NULL` pointer but that is something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sequencing is wrong.

`glewInit()` requires a current GL context to do its thing.  Without a current context it can't query the GL for entry points and leaves all of its function pointers (such as `glTexImage3D()`) set to NULL.

`glfwInit()` **DOES NOT** create a GL context nor make one current.

You need `glfwCreateWindow()` and `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` for that.